# Go through an array and check for certain values?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, pacman

I'm trying to create a function that will continuously loop through an array and check if there are still elements with a certain value. If there are no more of these elements, then I would like the function to execute a certain action.

I'm checking for `0`. If nothing is `= 0` then I want to display an image. Here's what I have, any suggestions?

```
function partiewin() {
    // On verifie si il y a encore des cases avec pour valeur '0' et si non, on     fini la partie

    var found = false;
    for (i = 1; i <= hauteur; i++) {
        for (j = 1; j <= largeur; j++) { 
            if (decor[i][j] != 0) {
                window.alert("You win");
                found = 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (!found) {
    }
}
```

This is the array

```
var decor = new Array(hauteur); 
for (i = 0; i <= hauteur; i = i + 1) {
    decor[i] = new Array(largeur);
}
```

The array is a long list of this shape :

```
decor[1][1] = '24'; decor[1][2] = '21'; decor[4][8]='0' ; etc
```

Shouldn't this work? I'm not getting any alerts or any answer whatsoever once all the '0' are technically gone from the map..

Comment: What is the issue? Are you getting an error?

Comment: Is it working? If not, in what way is it not working?

Comment: Well when in the PACMAN game and all the spaces with food are gone ( a n empty space is 2 and a food space is 0) i am not getting the window alert.

Comment: Are haueter & larguer integers?

Comment: Looking a little closer at your code. I don't think thats what decor[1][1] is being set to. See my answer for more details. Updating now...

Comment: Right above your `window.alert` add this code: `console.log(decor[i][j])` and post what is outputs in the console. If you don't know how to access the console, just push f12 on the browser

Comment: the console doesnt output anything and yes hauteur and largeur are integers, however the decor[i][j] is sometimes = to things like 11,1 or 14,4

Comment: Pretty sure your problem lies with your use of new Array(). If the console is not putting anything out or **undefined** the code is either not being run or there are no values. I updated my answer below to explain the `new Array()` constructor along with a link.

Comment: if this is my array , bcs i have a hard time understanding all the technical talk, what then should i be writing?

http://imgur.com/zrRRZgc

Answer (score 0):

Since your using an array, try the forEach method of arrays:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

In the end I imagine you're wanting to loop through a nested array of arrays.

http://jsfiddle.net/TylersDesk/yg8ag0vq/

```
var arrayOfArrays = [
[2,1,2,3,4,5],
[2,1,2,1,4,5],
[8,1,2,3,4,5],
[4,1,2,3,4,5],
[2,1,2,3,4,5],
[2,1,2,3,0,5],    
];

var flag = false;


for (i=0; i<arrayOfArrays.length; i++) {

    arrayOfArrays[i].forEach(function(value, index, array){
        console.log(value);
        if (value === 0) {
               console.log('Found a value');
               flag = true;
        }
    });
}

if (flag) {
 //do work   
}
```

There might be an issue with the way your declaring those arrays. For instance when you use new Array(numberOfIndexes) you're setting how many indexes are there for the array, but your nut exactly setting any VALUES.

So see this:

```
var hauteur = 40;
var largeur = 20;

var decor = new Array(hauteur); 
for (i=0; i <= hauteur; i=i+1)
{
    decor[i] = new Array(largeur);
}

console.log(decor);
console.log(decor[0][1]);
```

If hauteur and larguer are integers they are just creating an array of arrays without values.

Remember, if your passing a **SINGLE VALUE** to `new Array()`, its the **length** of the array, not the value. To set the value you would need to do something like `new Array(value1, value2, value3,)`

Read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

I'd suggest throwing in some log statements into your code to make sure your working with arrays and more specifically arrays that have values.

Comment: So this will go through my array and check for "0" ?

Comment: @JuCho Your looping through a multi nested array in the end. I have updated the answer along with a js fiddle.

Comment: Isn't workin, i edited my original post to be more clear

Comment: I don't quite get what a nested array is?

Comment: Nested array or multidimensional array. Its an array, that has arrays in it. So this is an array of numbers -> `var smallArray =  [1,2,3]`. To get the values you would use smallArray[0] and that would get the value of 1. A multidimensional array looks like this - `var multiArray = [ [], [], [] ]`. Thats 3 arrays inside 1 array. Then add values. `var multiArray = [ [1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9] ]`. So to get the value of 8 you would say `multiArray[2][1]`. Remember, indexes start with 0.

Comment: ok so i'm using a nester array i suppose? with the values largeur and hauteur. 

However I don't get why i'm getting no response. The code is perfectly logical, there are no errors in the console. Yet when i pick everything up nothing happens...